# Google Chrome on a fresh CentOS 7.1 not starting up

Tags: linux, google-chrome, centos, vnc

I am having a bad time trying to run Chrome on my CentOS 7.1 server. I know, it does not have a screen, it's a server. But I installed GNOME anyway and using VNC I can see the screen on a remote computer.

If I execute `export DISPLAY=:0;firefox &`  I can see the firefox running just fine!

The problem is with Chrome. I installed it on my CentOS 7.1 and when I run it as "root" (I know I shouldn't, but in this case I can only run it as root cause no other user is allowed in this server) I get error message that is WELL SPREADED on the Internet and nobody still found a good solution.

I try to run chrome with this:

```
google-chrome &
```

I get this error:

```
[root@ip-172-31-49-160 /]# google-chrome &
[4] 11889
[root@ip-172-31-49-160 /]# [1:1:0912/031926:ERROR:image_metadata_extractor.cc(111)] Couldn't load libexif.
[1:1:0912/031926:ERROR:nacl_fork_delegate_linux.cc(314)] Bad NaCl helper startup ack (0 bytes)
```

Unfortunatelly Chrome does not open. What am I doing wrong?

**

- [How do I remove this question? I already clicked FLAG and nothing
  happens](http://google.com)

**

Comment: related question: http://askubuntu.com/a/625691

Comment: No, in that question they say it was installed the i386 version but my version is x86_64. Many people on internet have this same error "Bad NaCl helper startup ack" for years, that's amazing nobody still came up with a solution

Comment: is this topic already dead? Should I request to delete it?

Comment: Try to open google chrome as regular user. Do not try to open it as root user. You will not get this error if you log into regular user account.

Answer (score 2):

The first error message you're getting should be solvable by installing `libexif`

```
apt-get install libexif12
```

Concerning the second (and most relevant) message, [Chrome is not designed to run as root](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=196353). Running your browser as root is indeed a bad idea from security point of view, so you should do as @testdemoTestlast says and run it using regular user account. If for some reasons you need to run it as root, try

```
google-chrome --no-sandbox --user-data-dir
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo yum install -y libexif
```

Answer (score 0):

try using the following command after installing libexif12

```
google-chrome --no-sandbox --disable-gpu --disable-software-rasterizer
```

and wait for few mins, chrome should start and give you prompt to check/uncheck defaults.

P.S: Meantime, you can check if processes are running.

> ps -aux | grep -i chrome